# Combining columns from two tables with nothing in common with postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Say I have these two tables (column id for table1, column letters for table2):

+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   3 |
|   4 |
|   5 |
+-----+

+---------+
| letters |
+---------+
| a       |
| b       |
| c       |
| d       |
| e       |
+---------+

How would I join these two tables together so that the following appears?:
+-----+---------+
| id  | letters |
+-----+---------+
|   1 | a       |
|   2 | b       |
|   3 | c       |
|   4 | d       |
|   5 | e       |
+-----+---------+

I am using postgreSQL-9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` function in join condition:

```
select id, letter
from (select id, row_number() over (order by 1) as rn from ids) i
join (select letter, row_number() over (order by 1) as rn from letters) l
on i.rn = l.rn;
```